# when i press tab the panel clears

Tags: c#, drawing, panel

Using DrawImageUnscaled my program draws a parobola or a line ...

If I press tab after the program draws, the panel in whith the image clears..

For my ox and oy axes i use ? and they disappear too...

```
System.Drawing.Pen linepen;
linepen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green);

System.Drawing.Graphics g = drawingboard.CreateGraphics();

g.DrawLine(linepen, 0, drawingboard.Height / 2, drawingboard.Width, drawingboard.Height / 2);
g.DrawLine(linepen, drawingboard.Width / 2, 0, drawingboard.Width / 2, drawingboard.Height);
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Use the Paint event to draw something.

Comment: I take it that the supplied code is NOT in, or being called from, an OnPaint(...) method, or Paint event handler. If that is so, you need to correct that, at least until you have a better grasp of how painting is done in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in DOT.NET you don't just paint what you want the user to see in a random place.  Instead each panel (and control) has an OnPaint function which is called when the control displays itself.  You want to modify this function to draw your new lines.

You will notice as you work with .NET that this function will get called multiple times when certain events happen in the application -- for example re-size.  This allows the programmer to change what is displayed when the window changes size.

Add your code above to the OnPaint function of the control and it should work much better.

I'm not sure what you mean by ox and oy -- you don't seem to have any code with them